# Auth::user() can't be read after loading a different blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

so I have a web project, and after I logged in, this is what it looks like. This is the ui for

```
admin.blade.php
```

[image: home page after log in]
as you can notice, at the upper right corner, the username is displayed, but when I click the drop down menu, to add a job vacancy
[image: job vacancy]
it will load the

```
createjob.blade.php
```

[image]
but after loading it, on the upper right corner of the page, the

```
Auth::user()->name
```

isn't displayed.

Here is my code for the 
    admin.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')

@section('content')
##insert html code here
@endsection
```

and this is my

```
appadmin.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>TeacHire</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        TeacHire
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">User Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/login') }}">School Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register as User</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('createjob') }}">Add Job Vacancy</a>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                        </a>


                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my

```
createjob.blade.php
```

is the same as

```
admin.blade.php
```

this is my

```
web.php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('account', 'AccountsController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/createjob', function(){
    return view('createjob');
});

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  });
```

and this is my

```
auth.php
```

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: did you used `auth` or `web` middleware?

Comment: can u show us your `web.php` file

Comment: @arun I have already edited the question and added my web.php and auth.php

Comment: put your route in `auth` middleware and check what happens

Comment: your `createJob` route is not included in the auth middleware it seems. You need to include a middlware of `auth` on that route and check again